# How to bring Webservice text into a Winform application

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, winforms, web-services

I am working a Winform Application that needs to access a webservice to get some basic information. The webservice exists, and the following is a link that brings text. Which basically is the customer name in Json format.

http://globalbox.com.py/api/getUSER.php?gb=3217

So, my point, i need to be able to read the name of the customer and put that into a string variable. How do I read this from Winforms?

I have no idea how to go about doing this... please help.
Visual Basic code would be better, or else C# will do.

thanks in advance!!

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: I have no idea where to begin. All I know is that its possible, and that I must get it done, but I would like some guidance as to how this can be accomplished.

Comment: by the way. the webservice returns data in Json.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/9c41b6ff-4f69-4993-a5c7-c141a6d303b8/parse-json-in-net-winform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick and dirty solution you could do the following

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Dim wc = New WebClient()
    Dim json As String = wc.DownloadString("http://globalbox.com.py/api/getUSER.php?gb=3217")
    Dim name As String = Regex.Match(json, "\[\[{\""NombreApellido\"":\""(.*?)\""\}\]\]").Groups(1).Value
    MessageBox.Show(name)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: great! thanks for laying that out for me. I will try your code out, and if it works will definetly mark as answered!! your a life saver!